# Currency format in OpenXML

Tags: asp.net

I am using OpenXML in .net 3.5 to export data table to Excel and want to show specific column as currency.
For example want to show 24.5 as $24.5.Please provide appropriate solution.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: I am trying code from http://www.lateral8.com/articles/2010/6/11/openxml-sdk-20-formatting-excel-values.aspx

Answer (score -1):

You can try in this way.

var data = (DataTable)Session["data"]; 
    var stringTable = XlsxRW.CreateStringTables(data, out lookupTable);
    using (var stream = new FileStream(Path.Combine(tempDir, @"xl\sharedStrings.xml"),
        FileMode.Create))
        XlsxRW.WriteStringTable(stream, stringTable); 
    using (var stream = new FileStream(Path.Combine(tempDir, @"xl\worksheets\sheet1.xml"),
        FileMode.Create))
        XlsxRW.WriteWorksheet(stream, data, lookupTable);